# Merging Overlapping Intervals with Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am working on the Merging Overlapping Intervals in LeetCode and I have been able to solve 2/3 test cases. The instructions are:

"Given an array of intervals where `intervals[i] = [starti, endi]`, merge all overlapping intervals, and return an array of the non-overlapping intervals that cover all the intervals in the input."

The first two test cases are:
Input: `intervals = [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]`
Input: `intervals = [[1,4],[4,5]]`
Where my outputs are `[[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]` and `[[1,5]]` respectively. Those are passing.

There is a third test case that I cannot for the life of me figure out why the expected output is the way it is.

The third test case:
Input: `[[1,4],[2,3]]`
Expected Output:`[[1,4]]`

This is my solution:

```
var merge = function(intervals) {
    // sort
    intervals.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
    
    let previous = intervals[0];
    let result = [previous];
    
    for(let i = 1; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        let current = intervals[i];
        if(previous[1] >= current[0]) {
            previous[1] = current[1];
        } else {
            result.push(current);
            previous = current;
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

My output is: `[[1,3]]`, because 4 is greater than 2, so there is an overlap.

It makes zero sense to me why the expected output would be `[[1,4]]`. Can anyone offer any insight on this?

Comment: `It makes zero sense to me why the expected output would be [[1,4]]` why does this not make sense to you? If you have the overlapping intervals `[1,4]` and `[2,3]` what would be the resulting interval that encloses both of these intervals? Does `[1,3]` enclose both?

Comment: @t.niese hmm ok I am now realizing that I made the common mistake of not fully understanding what the question was asking. What I was doing to merge the intervals was merging `intervals[0][0]` and `intervals[1][1]`, and my solution just happened to work for the first two test cases. So I guess what I need to do instead is compare `intervals[0][1]` and `intervals[1][1]` and take the larger of those two.

Comment: Yes exactly. You didn't think of the case that overlapping could also mean that one interval is completely enclosed in the other one. You just thought about the case when they insersect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact you are need, and not the clear and complete solution:

```js
class Interval {
  constructor(start, end) {
    this.start = start
    this.end = end
  }

  merge(interval2) {
    if (this.isOverlapped(interval2)) {
      let resultStart, resultEnd
      resultStart = this.start <= interval2.start ? this.start : interval2.start
      resultEnd = this.end >= interval2.end ? this.end : interval2.end
      return [new Interval(resultStart, resultEnd)]
    } else {
      return this.start <= interval2.start ? [this, interval2] : [interval2, this]
    }
  }

  isOverlapped(interval2) {
    let i1, i2
    if (this.start <= interval2.start) {
      i1 = this
      i2 = interval2
    } else {
      i1 = interval2
      i2 = this
    }
    return i1.end >= i2.start && i1.start <= i2.end
  }

  get print() {
    return `[${this.start}, ${this.end}]`
  }

  get toArray() {
    return [this.start, this.end]
  }
}

class Intervals {
  constructor() {
    this.collection = []
  }

  add(newInterval) {
    if (this.collection.length === 0) {
      this.collection.push(newInterval)
      return
    }

    let isMerged = false
    this.collection.forEach((existedInterval, index) => {
      if (newInterval.isOverlapped(existedInterval)) {
        this.collection[index] = existedInterval.merge(newInterval)[0]
        isMerged = true
      }
    })
    if (!isMerged) {
      this.collection.push(newInterval)
    }
  }

  get print() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.collection.map((x) => x.toArray))
  }
}

const test = [
  [new Interval(1, 2), new Interval(2, 3), true, [[1, 3]]],
  [new Interval(2, 3), new Interval(1, 2), true, [[1, 3]]],
  [new Interval(2, 4), new Interval(1, 3), true, [[1, 4]]],
  [new Interval(1, 3), new Interval(2, 4), true, [[1, 4]]],
  [new Interval(2, 4), new Interval(1, 5), true, [[1, 5]]],
  [new Interval(1, 2), new Interval(3, 4), false, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]],
  [new Interval(3, 4), new Interval(1, 2), false, [[1, 2], [3, 4]]],
  [new Interval(15, 18), new Interval(15, 18), false, [[15, 18]]],
]

// test is two intervals overlaps
test.forEach((testData) => {
  console.log(`test is overlapped[${testData[0].print}, ${testData[1].print}] - ${testData[0].isOverlapped(testData[1]) == testData[2] ? 'passed' : 'isnt passed'}`)
})

// test two intervals merging
test.forEach((testData) => {
  const result = testData[0].merge(testData[1])
  console.log(`test merging[${testData[0].print}, ${testData[1].print}] => [${result.map((x) => x.print)}] - ${JSON.stringify(result.map((x) => x.toArray)) == JSON.stringify(testData[3]) ? 'passed' : 'isnt passed'}`)
})

const test2 = [
  {
    input: [[1, 3], [2, 6], [8, 10], [15, 18]],
    expectedResult: [[1, 6], [8, 10], [15, 18]]
  },
  {
    input: [[1, 4], [4, 5]],
    expectedResult: [[1, 5]]
  },
  {
    input: [[1, 4], [2, 3]],
    expectedResult: [[1, 4]]
  },
  {
    input: [[1, 3], [5, 8], [2, 6]],
    expectedResult: [[1, 8]]
  },
]

test2.forEach((testData) => {
  const result = new Intervals()
  testData.input.forEach((testInterval) => result.add(new Interval(...testInterval)))
  console.log(result.print)
  console.log(`test merging multiple ${JSON.stringify(testData.input)} => ${JSON.stringify(testData.expectedResult)} - ${JSON.stringify(testData.expectedResult) == result.print ? 'passed' : 'isnt passed'}`)
})
```

See the last test. It's not passed.